# c# selenium image xpath download

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to download an image file via XPath using selenium. But I am getting the error that the file was not found.

```
      var resimadresi =  driveri.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img"));

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(resimadresi.Text, @"image.png");
```

Comment: Please share your code as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you provide the html you are trying to parse?

Comment: https://ebildirge.sgk.gov.tr/WPEB/amp/loginldap 
I want to download the verification code on the page and solve it with ocr.

Comment: resimadresi.GetAttribute("src") will give the address of image so you should use it to download image.

Comment: @MuratTüfekçi it will not work, because the image refreshes on every request.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do with fetchin src of image. Because on every request the image changes. You can take a screenshot of your page and extract the image with some bitmap operations.

```
void SomeMethod() {
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ebildirge.sgk.gov.tr/WPEB/amp/loginldap");
    Screenshot ss = driver.GetScreenshot();

    byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;

    Bitmap bmp;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(screenshotAsByteArray))
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    }

    Bitmap cropped = cropAtRect(bmp, new Rectangle(530, 350, 60, 40));
    cropped.Save("test.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

static Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
{
    Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb);
    g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
    return nb;
}
```

Here is the downloaded image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var resimadresi =  driveri.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(text(), "Güvenlik Anahtarı")]/following-sibling::node()[img]"));
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(resimadresi.Text, @"image.png");
```

**Güvenlik Anahtarı** is the text that I see beside the Verification code, feel free to replace it to whatever you see beside it. There was no translation to english option for me so, I can't really have an accurate text for the xpath.

Comment: It does not satisfy OP's needs. Image changes on every request.

Comment: I have editted the file, xpath should work and get the generated verification code since OP is looking for the verification code that gets refreshed each time.